# jQuery get rid of a:hover underline?

Tags: jquery, hover, underline

I'm just getting started with jQuery, having a little trouble.

Got a table of thumbnails, and I want each cell to be highlighted when I hover over the picture inside it. Got that part working. But I also want the picture inside the cell not to have an underline - this is inherited from the stylesheet `a:hover{text-decoration:underline}` . This is where I'm stuck, I don't think I'm setting the right thing.

I need to use inline styles, so my jQuery looks like:

```
$('[name*=thumb]').hover(
  function () {
    //as we hover over an item, change it's background, attempt to vaquish pesky underline
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id').replace('thumb', 'thumbcontainer')).css('background-color', '#cccccc'); 
    $('#' + this).css('text-decoration', 'none');  //doesn't work : (
  },
  function () {
    //fix bgs of items we're not hovering on
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id').replace('thumb', 'thumbcontainer')).css('background-color', '#ffffff'); 
  }
);
```

My HTML looks like this :

```
<td name="thumbcontainer8" id="thumbcontainer8"><a href="#" name="thumb8" id="thumb8"><img src="..." /></a></td>
<td name="thumbcontainer9" id="thumbcontainer9"><a href="#" name="thumb9" id="thumb9"><img src="..." /></a></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
  $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
```

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't this rule in your stylesheet do the trick?

```
a:hover img{text-decoration:none}
```

Comment: This is what CSS is for. Use jquery to add/remove css tags